# ¿Existe la palabra "modularizar" en español?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, palabras-raras

En ciencias computacionales es común utilizar el término "modularizar", para denotar algo que se divide en módulos (herencia del inglés "modularize").

Sin embargo, mi procesador de textos (Word) no reconoce "modularizar" como una palabra válida. El resultado de la [RAE para modularizar](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=modularizar) también sugiere que la palabra no existe.

Pero luego tenemos el sufijo [**-izar**](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=izar):

```
-izar.

(Del lat. -izāre).

1. suf. Forma verbos que denotan una acción cuyo resultado implica el significado del 
sustantivo o del adjetivo básicos, bien por reducción del complemento directo a cierto 
estado, en los transitivos, como en carbonizar, esclavizar, impermeabilizar, bien por 
la actitud del sujeto, en los intransitivos. Escrupulizar, simpatizar.
```

¿Es correcto entonces suponer que el sufijo -izar da validez a "modularizar" y que por lo tanto es una palabra válida?

Si bien puedo escribir *dividir en módulos* en lugar de *modularizar*, prefiero utilizar un solo término.

¿Existe otra palabra para esta idea?

Comment: Existe el verbo modular.

Comment: De hecho el verbo modular es lo correcto. Modularizar es una barbaridad.

Comment: Busco un verbo... Y el verbo modular no incluye la acepción que necesito.

Comment: "Modular" quiere decir "modulate".  No quiere decir "modularize".

Comment: @David: Modular se aplica en el ámbito de la física, en el estudio de las ondas, mira la RAE, no tiene nada que ver con modularizar que estoy de acuerdo que suena feo. Yo usaría dividir en módulos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sin duda [se usa](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularidad) palabras `modularidad` y `modularización`, aunque no se encuentran en el [diccinario de RAE](http://www.rae.es/rae.html). Por tanto me parece logico usar `modularizar`. Se puede encontrar varios ejemplos con dicha palabra:

- http://www.sidar.org/recur/desdi/traduc/es/xhtml/modxhtml/index.html
- http://www.fio.unicen.edu.ar/usuario/ariera/b6-0/Tutoriales/tut_Modularizacion.pdf
- http://www.sc.ehu.es/sfwseec/reec/reec12/reec1210.pdf

No hay que confundir `modularización` (y verbo `modularizar`) con `modulación` (y verbo `modular`). [Modulación](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulaci%C3%B3n_%28telecomunicaci%C3%B3n%29) se refiere a variacion de un parametro (amplitud o frequencia) de una onda y no tiene nada que ver con los módulos .

Comment: Muy buenos ejemplos. Me parece particularmente útil que sean publicaciones de distintos paises de habla hispana.

Comment: Sería útil detallar porqué modularizar es diferente a modular. :O)

Comment: El primer documento es una traducción mala de una especificación en inglés y que aún está en periodo de borrador. Para mi no es un ejemplo de que se use (y trabajo en IT). La palabra "ajolá" da 33.000 resultados en google y no por eso hay que usarla. Usen "segmentación" o "dividir en módulos".

Answer (score 2):

"*modularizar*" no aparece en el diccionario de la RAE, pero no es ninguna barbaridad.

"*modular*" es correcto, sólo que su significado no tiene absolutamente nada que ver, la barbaridad es confundirlo con *modularizar*.

"*programación modular*" es una expresión correcta, pero en ella el término "*modular*" es un adjetivo, no un verbo. Como se señaló arriba, el sufijo *-izar* sirve precisamente para formar verbos a partir de adjetivos o sustantivos, por tanto se podrían usar (y se usan) los términos "*modulizar*" (a partir del sustantivo "módulo") o "*modularizar*" (a partir del adjetivo "modular").

Comment: "la barbaridad es confundirlo con modularizar." ¿Puedes contarnos más sobre las diferencias entre modular y modularizar para afirmarlo? Pues yo estoy en desacuerdo.

Answer (score 2):

Modularizar es una palabra correctamente construida a partir del adjetivo y sufijo descritos.
Según la RAE, el hecho de que una palabra no exista en el diccionario no infiere que es incorrecta:
https://www.rae.es/duda-linguistica/si-una-palabra-no-esta-en-el-diccionario-es-incorrecta

Answer (score 1):

Modular sí existe como te comentan, pero se usa como adjetivo cuando se hace referencia a componentes, si la usas como verbo se trata de regular la intensidad de algo por ejemplo una señal como las de radio AM = Amplitud Modulada ó FM = Frecuencia Modulada dónde para transmitir la información se tiene que modular la señal en amplitud o frecuencia, la acción de *descomponer algo en módulos ó segmentos es* **segmentar**.

Answer (score -2):

http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_modular

Programación modular es el término correcto.